# Hope to disable collision between Robot model and object model While the Lidar could still detect the Object in Gazebo

Tags: navigation, gazebo, collision

Right now I have added this code to the collision element of the Object model sdf file, which allows the robot could go through the object very very slowly. Is there a way to make the robot have no collision with the object while I could still use Lidar to detect the objects in the Gazebo?



0
0



<collide_without_contact>true</collide_without_contact>

Comment: <surface>
    <friction>
     <ode>
      <mu>0</mu>
       <mu2>0</mu2>
      </ode>
     </friction>
     <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>true</collide_without_contact>
         </contact>
    </surface>

Comment: Welcome at RSE. Please edit, clarify and reformat your question using a code block to have a clear understanding what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Gazebo Classic (e.g. Gazebo 11), you can try to use `collide_without_contact`:

- See [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=collision#surface_contact) for the spec,
- See [here](https://github.com/arpg/Gazebo/blob/619218c0bb3dc8878b6c4dc2fddf3f7ec1d85497/test/worlds/collide_without_contact.world#L48-L52) for an example.

Unfortunately, this seems not implemented yet for 'new Gazebo' (i.e. 'Gazebo Sim', e.g. Gazebo Fortress or Garden or Harmonic).

A possible alternative (both for Gazebo Classic as well as Gazebo Sim) is to use a collision bitmask:

- See [here](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=collide_bitmask&cat=physics) for documentation

  (It is a Gazebo Classic documentation page, but I think the usage is identical in Gazebo Sim),
- See the `gz-sim` [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/shapes_bitmask.sdf) for an example demo world.